# DKIM Signing an email with MimeKit in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, smtp, dkim, mimekit

I am trying to get my website to send emails that are dkim signed. I found mimekit and have tried to implement the logic. I used several dkim checkers ([dkim key checker](https://protodave.com/tools/dkim-key-checker/) and [mail tester](https://www.mail-tester.com/spf-dkim-check)) to verify my dns record and it passes fine, but [dkim validators](https://dkimvalidator.com) and google and outlook show in the headers or page that the dkim fails in the email. The dkim validator above says:

> **Validating Signature**
>
> result = invalid
>
> Details: bad identity

The subroutine I am using:

```
Private Shared Sub DKIMSignAndSend(mailMessage As System.Net.Mail.MailMessage)
   Dim message As MimeMessage = MimeMessage.CreateFromMailMessage(mailMessage)
   Dim headersToSign() As HeaderId = New HeaderId() {HeaderId.From, HeaderId.Subject, HeaderId.Date}
   Dim domain As String = "domain.com"
   Dim selector As String = "1559659173.domain"
   Dim signer As DkimSigner = New DkimSigner(String.Format("{0}\Administration\dkim.pem", System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("WebsiteDirectory")), domain, selector)
   signer.SignatureAlgorithm = DkimSignatureAlgorithm.RsaSha1
   signer.AgentOrUserIdentifier = "domain.com"
   signer.QueryMethod = "dns/txt"
   message.Prepare(EncodingConstraint.SevenBit)
   message.Sign(signer, headersToSign, DkimCanonicalizationAlgorithm.Relaxed, DkimCanonicalizationAlgorithm.Simple)

   Using client As New MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient()
      With CType(ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp"), SmtpSection)
         client.Connect(.Network.Host, .Network.Port, .Network.EnableSsl)
         client.Authenticate(.Network.UserName, .Network.Password)
      End With
      client.Send(message)
      client.Disconnect(True)
   End Using
End Sub
```

I pass in a System.Net.Mail.MailMessage that has html **and** text alternate views and **attachments**.

Can anyone help with what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Stop me if I am wrong, but wouldn't it be a lot easier to set your keys up on the SMTP server than to go through this rigmarole? Maybe I've got the wrong idea, but it seems like the server should be handling this and not a client application.

Comment: I have no control of the smtp (it uses 1and1) and searching in the help on dkim gives very little. Plus I hope to figure this out so I can update a few other sites that also use email on their own domains to use dkim.

Comment: I would say its not such a good server then, what do you do otherwise? such as outlook, or any other mail you send outside of your application? Even [hmail](https://www.hmailserver.com/) has DKIM signing.

Comment: I have no interest in running a stmp server or service. I just want to get the mimekit working so I can update my site. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your Selector or AgentOrUserIdentifier are wrong.

Try signer.AgentOrUserIdentifier = "@domain.com"

Comment: Donation to the project made. :)